# fuel setup on mac / h5py setup on mac - hdf5.h file not found

Tags: python, macos, hdf5

I'm trying to install HDF5 on Mac and getting an error message:

```
fatal error: 'hdf5.h' file not found
```

This is confusing to me for a few reasons.

First of all, I was able to locate the file in question in Finder... In a folder apparently created in 2011. I bought the laptop new in 2013. So it looks like HDF5 should already have been on my computer? But I was trying to install fuel earlier today and it kicked me off with this error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
.. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
   You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
   library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
   variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
error: Setup script exited with 1
```

I tried moving the folder in question into the folder that I downloaded with the h5py programs in it, but had the same issue when I tried installing HDF5 again (`fatal error: 'hdf5.h' file not found`).

Has anyone else encountered issues like this before? I've googled the error messages but can't seem to find a good answer (especially for the issue with the program being unable to find the file that is apparently on my computer). This is my first time installing Python packages, so any tips at all are appreciated!

Comment: How exactly are you installing this package? Do you use `pip`?

Comment: no... unfortunately, i have been having lots of issues with pip as well. I am installing with the command  `python3 setup.py install`

Comment: So you found `hfd5.h`, in an `/some/path/include/hdf5.h`. Try setting as in (sh/bash) `export HDF5_DIR=/some/path`. As for the time stamps. I'd say the installation of HDF5 had those times, same as you can set a `ctime` on a file to be whatever you want. Side question what is `fuel`?

Comment: I was actually able to get around the problem with a `brew install`! But this is good info. `fuel` is a data framework for use with machine learning libraries, I'm using it with the `Blocks` library.